# Robot Framework: Generating Unique Random number

Tags: robotframework

I have to generate unique random numbers in robot framework. I have used "Generate Random String" to get random numbers. Command:

```
${random}   Generate Random String  1   [NUMBERS])
```

I gave the above statement in a for loop. Now I am able to get 'n' random numbers. But they are not unique. How do I make them unique?

Whats my case exactly: I want four unique random numbers ranging from 1 to 10. I am trying to give the generate random number command in for loop and in the second loop i am trying to compare it with first random value and so on. But this is not working.

Is there any simple logic to get 4 unique random numbers between 1 to 10?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bank account number in the EU needs to meet a specific standard: IBAN (International Bank Account Number) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number)). Perhaps the [Robot Framework Library for generating IBAN](https://github.com/kootstra/robotframework-dutchbankaccountnumber) can help?

Answer (score 12):

I think the random module's [sample](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) function is the most elegant solution. Here taking 4 out of the set of numbers from 1 to 10 inclusive:

```
${numbers}=    Evaluate    random.sample(range(1, 11), 4)    random
```

This returns a list of int's. If you want string representation of numbers...

```
${numbers}=    Evaluate    random.sample([unicode(x) for x in range(1, 11)], 4)    random
```

Comment: This looks way nicer than my solution :) Didn't know about sample(). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try below code. It will give you a 4 digit unique random number from "0123456789"

library    String

```
${PO_Number}    Generate random string    4    0123456789
```

I hope it will work for you as it worked for me.

Regards,
Arvind Kumar

Answer (score 1):

In order to get  4 random numbers from 1 to 10:

```
${Random Numbers}=     Evaluate  random.sample(range(1, 10),4)   random
```

Syntax:

```
${Random Numbers}=     Evaluate  random.sample(range(specify the range of number),(number of random numbers to be generated))    random
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Generate 4 Random And Unique Numbers
    ${numbers}    Create List    1    2    3    4    5
    ...    6    7    8    9    10
    ${random index}    Generate Random String    1    0123456789
    ${random number 1}    Set Variable    @{numbers}[${random index}]
    Remove From List    ${numbers}    ${random index}
    ${random index}    Generate Random String    1    012345678
    ${random number 2}    Set Variable    @{numbers}[${random index}]
    Remove From List    ${numbers}    ${random index}
    ${random index}    Generate Random String    1    01234567
    ${random number 3}    Set Variable    @{numbers}[${random index}]
    Remove From List    ${numbers}    ${random index}
    ${random index}    Generate Random String    1    0123456
    ${random number 4}    Set Variable    @{numbers}[${random index}]
    Remove From List    ${numbers}    ${random index}
    ${random numbers}    Create List    ${random number 1}    ${random number 2}    ${random number 3}    ${random number 4}
    [Return]    ${random numbers}
```

or with python

```
import random

def generate_4_random_and_unique_numbers():
    pool = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    random_numbers = []
    for index in range (0, 4):
        index = random.randint(0, len(pool)-1)
        random_numbers.append(pool[index])
        del pool[index]

    return random_numbers
```

In general, create a list of possible numbers. Pick number randomly from that list and then delete that number from the list. Repeat as many times as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I added these 2 lines and it worked fine:

*** Test Cases ***

```
Generate XYZ Random number
   ${rand_XYZ}=  generate random string  9  [NUMBERS]
   log to console  ${rand_XYZ}
```