# Any builtin in robot framework for selecting a random value from the dropdown list

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Is there any builtin in Robot Framework for selecting a random value from the dropdown list which is dynamically generated.

If not, any ways of implementing it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no builtin for that. You will have do something along those lines:

1. generate a random index using [Generate Random String](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Generate%20Random%20String) or [sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) like mentioned in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524771/robot-framework-generating-unique-random-number)
2. Use [Select from list by index](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20From%20List%20By%20Index) keyword on your list (from [Selenium2Library](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library)) using the random index you generated in the previous step.