# Robotframework: How to read a random row in csv file?

Tags: csv, robotframework

I made this code in python to read a row in a CSV file:

```
import csv

class CsvLibrary(object):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'Global'

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Read Cell Value in CSV File'

    def read_cell_value_by_row(self,filename,rownumber):
        #read an existing csv file
        userdata=[]
        user={}
        with open(filename,'rb') as csvfile:
            #read csv file as dictionary object
            reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            #read and store it as list of dictionary items
            userdata=list(reader)
            #get specific list item as a dictionary object
            user=userdata[rownumber-1]
            #return the dictionary object
            return user
```

Then in robotframework I do this script:

```
    ${row_number}=    Convert To Integer    1
    ${user_info}=    read_cell_value_by_row    UserInfo.csv    ${row_number}
    ${username}    Get From Dictionary    ${user_info}    username
    Log    ${username}
    ${password}    Get From Dictionary    ${user_info}    password
    Log    ${password}
    Input Text    ${login_username_textbox}    ${username}
    Input Text    ${login_password_textbox}    ${password}
```

But i don't know how I can read a random row on the CSV file, someone can help me?

Comment: In the same python file, why don't you simply write a "get_random row" method which can be used as a keyword_? Generate a random number between zero and the length of your data, and use that as an index to return a row.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're most of the way there, all you need is to generate the random number?  I would recommend using the String Library for simplicity, though you will need to control the number to ensure its within the bounds you want.

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html

```
${RANDOM_NUMBER}=    Generate Random String    2    [NUMBERS]
```

The above will offer a number between 00 and 99, ensure the 00 is handled of course.

A really nice alternative I found via search if you need unique numbers is from @ombre42 - [Robot Framework: Generating Unique Random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524771/robot-framework-generating-unique-random-number)

However, it doesn't sound like you need them to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Assuming there is a fixed range of rows from which to choose, I think the random.sample route is the way to go. So if cell indicies start at 1 and you have ${row count} rows, I would do    ${random row}=    Evaluate    str(random.choice(range(1, ${row count} + 1)))    random. Or the equivalent ${random row}=    Evaluate    str(random.choice(range(0, ${row count})) + 1)

Comment: @ombre42 

I'm trying to read the random row and then put this values in a input with robot framework, but I'm with some problems...

can you help me, and tell me what's wrong ?